# Getting Unexpected token with react-rails es6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ruby-on-rails-5

```
Rails 5.0.0.1
Ruby 2.3.1
```

I would of thought this would have been a presents issue but then again, it works for the person who created [the tutorial Im following](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/04/13/rails-react-npm-without-the-pain/) in conjunction with [this](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/03/09/modern-javascript-and-rails/). So, nothing fancy:

**Application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= cable
//= require_self
//= require react_ujs

window.$ = window.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');
var React = window.React = global.React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = window.ReactDOM = global.ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

require('./components');
```

**Components.js**

```
require( 'babel-polyfill' );
// Manually add components to window and global
// so that react_ujs and react-server can find them and render them.
window.Home = global.Home = require("./components/Home.js").default
// same issue if use *.es6.jsx
```

**Home.js (or es6.jsx)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-control">
        Home baby
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Home;
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem "browserify-rails"
gem 'react-rails
```

**config/application.rb**

```
# Configure Browserify to use babelify to compile ES6
config.browserify_rails.commandline_options = "-t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ]"

unless Rails.env.production?
    # Work around sprockets+teaspoon mismatch:
    Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(spec_helper.js)

    # Make sure Browserify is triggered when
    # asked to serve javascript spec files
    config.browserify_rails.paths << lambda { |p|
        p.start_with?(Rails.root.join("spec/javascripts").to_s)
    }
end
```

**npm**

```
npm install browserify browserify-incremental babelify babel-preset-es2015 --save
```

The Unexpected token refers to the first `<div>`, why?

Comment: Please, write solution, i has the same issue.

Comment: @SergeijBelevskij 4months seems like 4 yrs ago; I can hardly remember. I think I ran `rails assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0):

The JSX syntax is not being compiled, probably because you need to add the react babel preset to your browserify config.

install package:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
```

config/application.rb

```
config.browserify_rails.commandline_options = "-t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]"
```

Comment: I have that in my `package.json` file and with your browserify config I get: `Couldn't find preset "es2015," relative to directory`

Comment: Sorry, I think there's no comma in between the preset names, so `[ es2015 react ]`

Comment: yes `config.browserify_rails.commandline_options = "-t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]"` I also have in root a `.babelrc` with `{ "presets": ["es2015"] }` but same issue

Comment: Remove the comma between es2015 and react in your commandline_options.

Comment: Made a typo; but same issue

Comment: You could try adding react to your .babelrc presets. If you are getting unexpected token on that first <, that means babel isn't set up correctly to compile JSX, so you need to get that react preset running in browserify (or webpack) somehow.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same problem